# Can I change the initial pose of my p3dx when I launch the .launch file?

Tags: ros, gazebo, p3dx, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi ros users:

How can i do that my model of p3dx appears where I want when I run gazebo? For example on x=3 y=3.
is there anyway to do that? so, change the initial pose of my p3dx.
My pkg of the model is this https://github.com/RafBerkvens/ua_ros_p3dx

Thanks!!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210798/can-i-change-the-initial-pose-of-my-p3dx-when-i-launch-the-.launch-file?/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do this by modifying your gazebo.launch file.

```
<node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
        respawn="false" output="screen" args="-urdf -model p3dx -x 3 -y 3 -param robot_description" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Progtologist](https://answers.ros.org/users/11081/progtologist/) with karma: 101 on 2015-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2015-06-10**:
That is the way! thanks